# include_once being ignored

Tags: php

Okay.

So on line 37 on this script http://ideone.com/grapQ the include_once command is basically just being ignored and the content I am trying to show is not showing up at all, not even a error message.

I tried enabled error reporting and not one a single error is being shown.

Also i tried using Echo and the same issue persist.

Does anyone have any ideas on why its being ignored and not even a error message is being shown? More than luck just its just something basic!

Comment: Couldn't add code here as its alot of code!

Comment: Did you try [error_reporting(E_ALL)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of the main script?

Comment: @Mythril Yes and nothing is showing up!

Comment: Most servers don't allow inclusion of external php files because of the risky nature of doing so.

Comment: Might I suggest the use of 'require' instead of 'include_once'

Comment: @Vulcan Thats probably why than! Whats a work around than? All it is, is just text saying if the version is up to date or not!

Comment: Issue is resloved, due to using external link which isn't allowed by the machine. Using an iframe instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot include remote files as it is in `PHP 5.2.0` and later versions. If you want to use remote `URL`  **allow_url_include** must be enabled for these. Refer [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a semi-colon on the end of that include statement:

```
include_once('http://outside-resources.ultimatesphider.com/us-resources/2.0.1/2.0.1announce.php');
```

Additionally, when I tested it (just that line) here on my local machine, I got the following errors:

```
Warning: include_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /var/www/test.php on line 5 
Warning: include_once(http://outside-resources.ultimatesphider.com/us-resources/2.0.1/2.0.1announce.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /var/www/test.php on line 5 
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'http://outside-resources.ultimatesphider.com/us-resources/2.0.1/2.0.1announce.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/test.php on line 5
```

Deepak's answer has more information on allowing external files that probably applies to your question.

Comment: Thanks, The issue was that I was including a external link, and not a local machine. The above also helped me +1

Answer (score 0):

follow the link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php